# Resizing datagrid does not work

Tags: wpf, animation, datagrid

I can resize datagrid in the window until I excecute this code:

```
    // Handle the tabcontrol animation 
DoubleAnimation dbTbViewsAnimation =
    new DoubleAnimation(dToTabHeightParameter, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0,0,1)));
this.tbViews.BeginAnimation(TabControl.HeightProperty, dbTbViewsAnimation);


// Handle the tabcontrol animation 
DoubleAnimation dbCurrentPlaylistHeightAnimation =
    new DoubleAnimation(dToCurrentPlaylistParameter, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)));
this.dgCurrentPlaylist.BeginAnimation(DataGrid.HeightProperty, dbCurrentPlaylistHeightAnimation);
```

What is the problem in this code and why it blocks the datagrid resizing?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See [Timeline.FillBehavior Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx). The default value is [HoldEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.fillbehavior.aspx). You could use a constructor overload to change this behavior.

```
DoubleAnimation dbTbViewsAnimation =
    new DoubleAnimation(dToTabHeightParameter,
                        new Duration(new TimeSpan(0,0,1)),
                        FillBehavior.Stop);
```

FYI: [How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx)